# Hibernate EntityManagerFactory EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, entitymanager

Can I create an `EntityManager` from `EntityManagerFactory` outside a bean. If so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 2):

In a non-managed environment (this is what you mean by outside a bean, right?), then you typically use:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPu"); 
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin()
...
em.getTransaction().commit();
emf.close();
```

Check the other factory method allowing to pass properties as parameter (they will override any values that may have been configured elsewhere): [`Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(String, Map)`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html#createEntityManagerFactory(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map)).

#### See also

- [Using the Java Persistence API in Desktop Applications](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/persistenceapi/)
- [An Introduction to Java Persistence for Client-Side Developers](http://www2.java.net/article/2006/05/19/introduction-java-persistence-client-side-developers)